# How to disable Java's SSL session resumption

Tags: java, ssl, connection

I need to test our nginx new SSL connection handshake performance, so we need to disable the ssl resumption function either in the client side or in the server side.

It's very easy to implement it in nginx side, just off the session cache and session ticket, but each time when I want to test the production's performance, I have to disable the function, which is annoying.

So another way is to disable session resumption in the client side, and our benchmark program is written by Java. We found that the appropriate method is SSLContext's setSessionCacheSize and setSessionTimeout function, but if the value is set to 0, then I found that all the ssl connection is reused, so I have to set it to 1, which result in 90% connections resumption in my testing.

So my question is how to disable ssl session resumption in Java JDK 8 when making SSL connection with the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get the `SSLSession` from the socket.
2. Call [`SSLSession.invalidate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSession.html#invalidate--).

Comment: And then how to use httpclient with this socket?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't see `HttpClient` mentioned in your question. You got hold of the `SSLSessionContext` somehow: if you can do that you can certainly get hold of the `SSLSocket`.